# Is it possible to execute code while a Promise's status is pending?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise

Usually, the desired behavior is that a developer would like to make sure that no other code would get executed before a particular promise is fulfilled or rejected. That's nowadays easily achieved by using the async / await pattern.

However, I have a situation where it is desirable that other code needs to be executed in the meantime, while a Promise (which is most probably going to be resolved successfully!). That's why I'm not setting an await modifier on puropse; so far so good. But still, how do I make sure that a piece of code gets executed for the time window when a promise's status is "pending" instead of "resolved"? Like, before it's known whether it is rejected or not?

I imagine something like a while loop, but since the [[PromiseStatus]] property is not accessible, I need to type 'then' every time in order to have access to the promise value, and using (then) endlessly doesn't really seem like working solution.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: That's how Promises always work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research, post a [Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and specifically say where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just the way promises natively work. You can start them by not having an `await` keyword and then `await`  when you're ready. The demo below shows this in action.

```js
async function dummyPromise(){
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,3000));
}

async function test(){
   var prom = dummyPromise();
   console.log("This line runs while the promise is pending");
   await prom;
   console.log("This line runs after the promise resolves");

}

test();
```